# Is it true that $X \times_Y X \cong X$?

Tags: category-theory, pullback

We work in an arbitrary category with objects $X$ and $Y$. Given a map $X \to Y$, is it true that there is a unique isomorphism between the fiber product $X \times_Y X$ and $ X$?

Comment: No. Consider for instance the case of $Y$ being the terminal object - then $X\times_Y X=X\times X$, which certainly isn't always isomorphic to $X$.

Comment: That's right, thanks!

Comment: Adding some conditions on the morphism $X\to Y$ may render that statement true

Comment: For example in the category of sets if $X\to Y$ is a monomorphism then, yes $X \times_{Y} X \simeq X$.

Comment: @jeanmfischer In fact, in *any* category, if $f$ is a monomorphism, then the fiber product is isomorphic to $X$.

Comment: Moreover, $f$ is a monomorphism _if and only if_ the fiber product exists and the induced morphism from $X$ to the fiber product is an isomorphism.